# SSAS Tabular Model "All" member value

Tags: excel, powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have an SSAS Tabular Model project for which the language is set to "French". Also, the SSAS Server itself has the language set to "French". The user uses a French version of Excel and Windows as well.

When the user explores the model and puts a column as a filter in Excel, they see "All" in that filter. But when doing the same in Power BI, they see "Tout" (translation of All in French).

The user wants to correct that "All" value in Excel into "Tout" for matching their culture.

My questions are:

- Why Excel is showing an English work despite all the components are in French: Windows OS, Excel itself, the SSAS Tabular Model culture, and the SSAS Server are all in French?
- How to translate that "All" appearing in Excel filter into the French equivalent "Tout"?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you try it without ssas connection ?
I can't try with SSAS but when I use a pivot table based on random data in other sheet I see "tous" as filter selection.

Comment: @Carbon4horse for the other sources I don't see the problem.